# How to rotate the entire page in Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I would like to rotate an entire page, including all of the shapes and text on it.

I see here that you can *supposedly* hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click-drag the corner of the page to do it like described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/rotate-a-page-HP085050946.aspx).

... however I can't get this to work.  Hovering over the corner does nothing initially, and when I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> the cursor becomes a scale/resize icon, rather than a rotate icon (per the MS article I linked to above).  I have tried other modifier key combinations while hovering, but nothing seems to produce the rotate icon mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've explored with both Visio 2010 and Visio 2013 to compare the behavior.

**Visio 2010** does indeed let you rotate the page by holding down the **Control** key.

With **Visio 2013**, this feature has been removed. The Control key no longer offers the rotation icon.

Furthermore, if you perform the rotation with Visio 2010 and then save the file you'll notice that when Visio 2010 loads that file the page will appear rotated. However, when that same file is loaded by Visio 2013 then the rotation is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Under the Design tab, there is an Orientation button (far left on the Ribbon):

[image: Design tab screenshot]